# Link de menu não funcionando com o $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular-providers

Estou encontrando problemas para trabalhar com o *$routeProvider* do *Angular.js*, tenho um *link* em um menu no qual irá ser mapeado via *route* do *angular*, e posteriormente irá chamar uma *action* no *Spring*, mas o mesmo não funciona. Sempre me retorna 404 e já alterei a *url* de todas as formas possíveis e mesmo assim não funciona.

Abaixo está o link *HTML*, assim como a configuração do meu *provider*:

```
<li>
    <a class="tooltip-tip ajax-load" href="#" title="Clientes"><i class="entypo-user"></i><span>Clientes</span></a>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="tooltip-tip2 ajax-load" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/auth/#/customer" title="Novo Cliente"><i class="entypo-newspaper"></i><span>Novo Cliente</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>




  var app = angular.module('customer', []);

    app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
        console.log('Acesso a Configuração do RouteProvider.');
        $routeProvider.when('/customer', {
            templateUrl: '/auth/customer',
            controller: 'customerController'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/customer'
        });
    });
```

Comment: Tente trocar o href lá em cima para: `href="#/customer"`

Comment: Então @PedroLaini eu tentei, mas não acontece nada! A *url* meio que fica concatenada: `.../viatge/auth/home#/customer` e não entra no *debug* tanto do *Google Chrome* quanto minha *action* no lado servidor.